# Deleting an default argument inside function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, del

I have tried the following in the console:

```
>>> def f(l=[]):
...     l.append(1)
...     print(l)
...     del l
... 
>>> f()
[1]
>>> f()
[1, 1]
```

What I don't understand is how the interpreter is still able to find the same list `l` after the delete instruction.
From the documentation `l=[]` should be evaluated only once.

Comment: Each time the function is called the local variable `l` is created and set to the value of the default argument. The default argument's value is created on function definition, but the variable `l` is created each time the function runs.

Comment: `del` of a local variable, right at the end of a function, is NEVER going to have any effect whatsoever.  It's exactly what's going to happen to the variable anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *variable* is not the object. Each time the function is called, the local variable `l` is created and (if necessary) set to the default value.

The object `[]`, which is the default value for `l`, is created when the function is defined, but the variable `l` is created each time the function runs.

Comment: Note that if the goal is to clear the contents of the `list`, `del l[:]` would do that; `l` would remain bound to the `list` (being unbound when the function returns immediately thereafter as normal), but the list itself would have its contents deleted so it's clear for the next call.

Comment: Thanks, actually the goal was just understanding what happens with `del` for a default function argument since I did not find anything about that in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a element for the list,`del l[:]` should be used.If u use just `l` the list will remain itself.

```
def f(l=[]):
l.append(1)
print(l)
del l[:]
print(l)
>>> f()
[1]    #element in the list
[]     #list after deletion of the element
>>> f()
[1]
[]
>>> f()
[1]
[]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately your code is not indented correctly. See [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format it correctly.